# Xamarin Forms crossplatform BBCode support

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, bbcode

I'm creating crossplatform app in Xamarin - just a simple forum. I can get post text, but it looks just as text with tags, but I need to show all the formatting, quotes, images, smiley and etc. Is there any crossplatform solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just combine a `WebView` (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/) control with a bbcode parser: 
https://bbcode.codeplex.com
https://github.com/charliesome/bbsharp

Comment: I'm trying. There is no problem with `WebView`, but I can't use `CodeKicker.BBCode` because of `Assemble not found` for `System.Web`.

Comment: You are probably using PCL project. You should change your PCL version to another which is compatible with System.Web or download library source and recompile it as a Xamarin compatible / PCL library

Comment: Yes, PCL. But it doesn't matter because I found another BBCode parser [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/855611/Simple-Text-Markup-Language-STML-Parser). Thanks for your answer.